# Creation of a Function that transforms sentence in Python

Tags: python, function

So I am trying to create a function that calls two functions within the function where one function called "encode" checks if the first letter of a word is a vowel and if yes it will add "way" to the end of the word and if the word starts with a consonant it will move the first letter to the third position in the word and adds gar.

my problem is creating that function that calls from the encode function to read a sentence and change each word accordingly based on the first letter.

```
So here are some text cases for the function: 

encode() function: 
The output will look like this:
Please enter your message: python is fun
The secret message is:  ythonpar isway unfar

translation is correct when words are separated by more than one space character.
Please enter your message: simple     is better than complex
The secret message is:  implesar isway etterbar hantar omplexcar
```

Here is my script. They are suppose to be connected.

```
def get_input():
    user_input = input('Please enter a message: ')
    more_message = True
    while more_message:
        user_input = input('Please enter a message: ')
        if not user_input==' ':
            more_grades = False
        return


def starts_with_vowel(word):
    while True:
        data = word
        the_vowel = "aeiou"
        if word[0].lower() in the_vowel:
            print ('true')
        else:
            print ('false')
        return


def encode(word):
    while True:
        data = starts_with_vowel(word)
        the_vowel = "aeiou"
        if word[0].lower() in the_vowel:
            new_word=word+'way'
            print ('The secret word is:',new_word)
        else:
            new_word2=word+'ar'
            scrambled_word=new_word2[1:-2]+new_word2[0]+new_word2[3]+new_word2[4]
            print (scrambled_word)
            print ('The secret word is:',new_word2)
        return


def translate(text):
    secret_message= encode(text)
    return (secret_message)

translate('gin is a boy')
```

Comment: just a question, whats with the `while True:` lines in the functions...?

Comment: I am new to this so I used to run a loop to check if the word contains certain attributes. IF you have a better way of doing it or know the proper way. Please let me know so I can improve my code.

Comment: There are a number of style and logic issues with this code..

Comment: Can you help me with that?

Comment: For starters (and I'm not going to list all of the problems), your functions should return values, not print them.

Comment: You are unfortunately conflating printing and returning. When two functions in your program communicate with each other they do so via parameters and return values. You've got the parameters passing correctly, but you aren't properly returning results from your functions. You're printing them instead. You are also improperly using while loops, so you should figure out your confusion around iteration and what it's for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better approach would be to use split on the sentence (input) and loop over the words:

```
vowels = 'aeiou'
sentence = 'python is fun'
new_words = []

for word in sentence.split():
  if word[0].lower() in vowels:
    new_words.append(word+'way')
  else:
    new_words.append(word[1:3]+word[0]+word[3:]+'gar')

' '.join(new_words)

'ytphongar isway unfgar'
```

Comment: Thank for fixing a part! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think in the first part of the code you will need to change the more_grades section with more_message, because first off more_grades has not been initialized and more_messages is controlling your loop so i think that's what you meant to do. Don't worry I believe that's only one error I have caught I will check the rest of the code and  get back to you. Don't stress it.Happy coding :-)

Comment: I am new to coding and I am trying my best to learn how to code in python.

Comment: Can you actually send me the problem you have to solve, it is kind of unclear of what you are trying to do by just reading your code. Therefore I can help you further. Don't stress, Meaning the link to the problem you have to solve, And I understand how frustrating this could be for you, I have been there, haha don't worry it will definitely get easier, and you will fall in love with it just don't let boredom frustration and stress get to you those are feelings that come to all of us on our way to mastery. Happy coding :-)

Comment: @DagmawiNadew lets open it in chat. How do I open this in chat with you?

Comment: You can't chat on on here, unless you have points, do you have twitter?

Comment: @DagmawiNadew sent you a tweet! :)